# Splitting String in case of a new line

Tags: java

I have a method in java which returns the updated lines of a flat file as a "String". I  am receiving the String as a bunch of lines, what i want to do is to separate the String line by line. How can i do that in java?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest make use of system property `line.separator` for this splitting to **make your code work on any platform** eg: *nix, Windows, Mac etc. Consider code like this:

```
String str = "line1\nline2\nline3";
String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
System.out.printf("After Split - %s%n", Arrays.toString(str.split(eol)));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...:) how to split the string containing tab spaces???

Comment: Sure just change the 2nd line above to this: `   String eol = '[' + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t]";`

Answer (score 3):

```
String lines[] = fileString.split("\\r?\\n"); //should handle unix or win newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

I  am  not sure about with single string  separator  .

but i roughly write a method that may be relevant to you .

```
public void splitter  (DocumentEvent e) {
    String split[], docStr = null;
    Document textAreaDoc = (Document)e.getDocument();

    try {
        docStr = textAreaDoc.getText(textAreaDoc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), textAreaDoc.getEndPosition().getOffset());
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    split = docStr.split("\\n");
}
```